Using ee.Image.stratifiedSample with .smileRandomForest, .train, and .classify, in python?
I want to use .stratifiedSample to create training data from an ensemble layer with four classes (labeled 0-3, representing agreement of spectral indices), then to use that output to train a .smileRandomForest classifier and classify the input image.
The code runs, but the .classify step produces an image object that I can't visualize and is difficult to examine (.bandNames() and .display() don't work on it). So while visualizing is producing the error, I think the problem might come from me misapplying the sampling or classifier.
Could someone please advise on how to correct the way I'm using .stratifiedSample to prep input for use with .smileRandomForest here?
The visualizing error is:
EEException: Classifier.train, argument 'inputProperties': Invalid type.
Expected type: List.
Actual type: Image<[NDWI_water, MNDWI_water, AWEI_water, B8A, B12, NDWI_reclass, MNDWI_reclass, AWEI_reclass, B8A_NIR_reclass, B12_SWIR_reclass, Ensemble_Vote]>.
My code is below:
#Imports
import numpy
import ee  
import geemap
ee.Authenticate()
ee.Initialize()

#Constants
i_date = '2024-02-10'
f_date = '2024-03-01'
lon = -80.205595
lat = 25.748059
geometry = ee.Geometry({
    'type': 'Polygon',
    'coordinates': [[            #lat, lon
        [-80.267610, 25.796023], #Top left, 
        [-80.263518, 25.730725], #Lower left, 
        [-80.121574, 25.730725], #Lower right, 
        [-80.121574, 25.810281], #Top right
    ]],
})
geometry_bounds = geometry.bounds()
point_centroid= geometry.centroid(maxError=1)

# Define functions

def addNDWI(image):
    ndwi = (image.select('B3').subtract(image.select('B8A'))).divide(image.select('B3').add(image.select('B8A'))).rename('NDWI_water')
    return image.addBands(ndwi)

def addMNDWI(image):
    mndwi = (image.select('B3').subtract(image.select('B11'))).divide(image.select('B3').add(image.select('B11'))).rename('MNDWI_water')
    return image.addBands(mndwi)

def addAWEI(image):   
    awei = (((image.select('B2').add(image.select('B3').multiply(ee.Number(2.5)))).subtract(
             (image.select('B8A').add(image.select('B11'))).multiply(ee.Number(1.5))).subtract(
             image.select('B12').multiply(ee.Number(.25)))).divide(
             image.select('B2').add(image.select('B3')).add(image.select('B8A')).add(image.select('B11')).add(image.select('B12')))).rename('AWEI_water')
    return image.addBands(awei)

def reclass_band(image, bandname, threshold, newname):
    bandtoreclass = image.select(bandname)
    reclassed = bandtoreclass.where(bandtoreclass.lt(threshold), 0).where(bandtoreclass.gte(threshold), 1).rename(newname)
    return image.addBands(reclassed)

def tally(image):
    tallied = (image.select('NDWI_reclass')).add(image.select('MNDWI_reclass')).add(image.select('AWEI_reclass')).toUint8().rename('Ensemble_Vote')
    return image.addBands(tallied)

# Get imagery (Sentinel 2)
s2_filtered = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR').filterBounds(geometry).filterDate(i_date, f_date)
s2_clipped_collection = ee.ImageCollection(s2_filtered.map(lambda image: image.clip(geometry)))

# Add spectral indices
s2_ndwi_added = s2_clipped_collection.map(addNDWI) 
s2_mndwi_added = s2_ndwi_added.map(addMNDWI)
s2_just_ndwi_mndwi_awei = s2_mndwi_added.map(addAWEI)

# Reclass indices to binary
s2_ndwi_reclass_added = s2_just_ndwi_mndwi_awei.map(lambda image: reclass_band(image, 'NDWI_water', 0, 'NDWI_reclass'))
s2_mndwi_reclass_added = s2_ndwi_reclass_added.map(lambda image: reclass_band(image, 'MNDWI_water', 0, 'MNDWI_reclass'))
s2_awei_reclass_added = s2_mndwi_reclass_added.map(lambda image: reclass_band(image, 'AWEI_water', 0, 'AWEI_reclass'))
s2_B8A_reclass_added = s2_awei_reclass_added.map(lambda image: reclass_band(image, 'B8A', 850, 'B8A_NIR_reclass'))
s2_B12_reclass_added = s2_B8A_reclass_added.map(lambda image: reclass_band(image, 'B12', 800, 'B12_SWIR_reclass'))

# Calculate ensemble vote (0-3, how many indices agree a pixel is water)
s2_tallied = s2_B12_reclass_added.map(tally)

# Get one image to test the sampling method on.
s2_List_b=ee.ImageCollection(s2_tallied).toList(s2_tallied.size());
s2_single_Image_b=ee.Image(ee.List(s2_List_b).get(1));
s2_single_Image_b  

### The following does not produce expected output:

# Collect stratified random points in the four ensemble classes (0-3)
stratified = s2_single_Image_b.stratifiedSample(
      numPoints=1000,
      classBand='Ensemble_Vote',
      geometries=True
    )

# Attempt to create classifier, train using points collected from the ensemble layer, and then classify an image using the trained classifier
RF_classifier = ee.Classifier.smileRandomForest(numberOfTrees=30)
Training_RF_classifier = RF_classifier.train(
    features=stratified,  
    classProperty="Ensemble_Vote", 
    inputProperties=s2_single_Image_b,
)
classifiedImage = s2_single_Image_b.classify(Training_RF_classifier)

# none of these produce information:
band_names = classifiedImage.bandNames()
display('Band names:', band_names)
classifiedImage.propertyNames()

# View
m.addLayer(classifiedImage.select('Ensemble_Vote'), viz2, 'Classified')
m

#EEException: Classifier.train, argument 'inputProperties': Invalid type.
#Expected type: List<String>.
#Actual type: Image<[NDWI_water, MNDWI_water, AWEI_water, B8A, B12, NDWI_reclass, MNDWI_reclass, #AWEI_reclass, B8A_NIR_reclass, B12_SWIR_reclass, Ensemble_Vote]>.



The inputProperties argument of stratifiedSample should be a list of bands, you currently have your image. You can replace s2_single_Image_b by s2_single_Image_b.bandNames().
Also you might consider selecting just bands of interest when classifying - you probably don't want to use bands like 'MSK_SNWPRB', 'MSK_CLDPRB', etc. So you could even have s2_single_Image_b.select('B.*', 'NDWI_reclass', 'MNDWI_reclass', 'AWEI_reclass', 'MNDWI_reclass', 'AWEI_reclass').bandNames() as the input for inputProperties.
Your stratified variable is returning a feature collection with no elements. The dropNulls option on stratifiedSample, which defaults to true, throws away any samples in which any of the bands are masked. For that image, you might have some empty bands, which returns no features in the end. Set dropNulls to False, or remove those bands before sampling.
Finally, the 'COPERNICUS/S2_SR' collection is deprecated. Consider using 'COPERNICUS/S2_SR_HARMONIZED'.
